# Combining many sort ranks into one master sort rank

Tags: sql, sorting, integer

Say I have some sorted result from a SQL query that looks like:

```
x y z 
0 0 0 
0 0 1 
0 0 2
0 1 0
0 1 1 
0 2 0
0 2 1
```

Where `x`, `y` and `z` are sort ranks. These sort ranks are always greater than 0, and smaller than 500mil.

---

Is there a way to combine the values from `x`, `y` and `z` into one "master" sort rank? Sorting the dataset using this "master" sort rank should result in the same ordering.

I'm thinking I can do something with bit shifting but I am not sure...

Comment: Which version of SQL are you using (e.g. MySQL, SQL Server, Postgres, etc.) ?

Comment: @TimBiegeleisen Although I am planning on implementing this on a SQL db, I really just said "SQL" just for the example. I am looking for a general solution, ignoring the limitations of SQL. I might implement this in Pandas too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming that every value in each of the three columns in between 1 and 500 million, you could use the following formula to generate a unique rank:
1000000
    z + (500 x 10^6)*y + (500 x 10^6)*(500 x 10^6)*x

To generate this rank you could use the following query:

```
SELECT
    x, y, z,
    z + (500 * 1000000)*y + (500 * 1000000)*(500 * 1000000)*x AS master_rank
FROM yourTable;
```

The reason this works can be seen by examining say the `z` and `y` columns.  The *largest* value from `z` is 500 million, which is guaranteed to be *smaller* than the smallest value in `y`, which is 1 billion.  This logic applies to the whole formula.  This approach is similar to using a bit mask, on a larger scale.

Note that I assume that your version of SQL can tolerate numbers this large.  If it doesn't, then you might want to consider another approach here, possibly just ordering as @Gordon mentioned in his answer.  Besides this, having 1 bil x 1 bil records would make for a very large table and would have other problems.

Answer (score 1):

Do you mean something like this?

```
order by x * 10000 + y * 100 + z
```

(You would adjust the numbers for the width you need.)

I'm not sure why you would want to do that instead of:

```
order by x, y, z
```

If you do combine into a single value, be careful about integer overflow.